# Using ContentObserver with IntentService

Tags: android, android-service, intentservice, contentobserver

I want to use IntentService as it creates a work queue and handles asynchronous requests. I am registering a ContentObserver within service. Docs say that IntentService stops itself when it runs out of work.
 I want my Service to stop only after ContentObserver's onChange() method is called. Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Step #1: Switch from `IntentService` to `Service`.

Step #2: Call `stopSelf()` in your `Service` when your criteria ("after ContentObserver's onChange() method is called" and anything else) are met.

Comment: My current code already does that. But I wanted to switch to IntentService as it provides work-queue which saves me from bothering about multi-threading.

Comment: @droidmad: Use `Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()` for your work queue: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newSingleThreadExecutor%28%29 Your proposed solution does not save you "from bothering about multi-threading", considering that your `onChange()` call will be made on a separate thread from the thread used by the `IntentService`.